# How to sever multipule angular projects in one nginx server with same domain name

Tags: angular, nginx

I want to serve multiple angular applications in same server with same server name.

I have generated Angular dist files like this:

```
    ng build --prod --base-href /app1/
    ng build --prod --base-href /app2/
```

my nginx-default file:

```
    server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name dav-******-app.****india.cloudapp.azure.com;
       root /var/www/App1/;
       index index.html;
       location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
     }


    server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name dav-******-app.****india.cloudapp.azure.com;
       root /var/www/App2/;
       index index.html;
       location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two server blocks. Rename `App1` and `App2` folders lowercase. Try the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name dav-******-app.****india.cloudapp.azure.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html;
    location ~ ^/(?<app>EricApp|AppleApp) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$app/index.html;
    }
}
```

Your apps would be accessible under `your-domain/EricApp/` and `your-domain/AppleApp/`. Your folders where these apps would be placed must be `/var/www/EricApp` and `/var/www/AppleApp`.

Comment: my actual app name will be like this:  EricApp, AppleApp, for this what could be the regex.

Comment: @sureshkumar Updated an answer.

Comment: I have deployed the angular apps but If try to access the page like this: http//:DNS/ericapp/ I am seeing empty page...

Comment: @sureshkumar What are your `base-href` actual values? What are the names of folders where are your apps are located? What should be the server answer to request without app prefix (`http://your-domain/`)? Do you understand that the paths and app prefixes are case-sensitive?